# What is the correct syntax for iterating over records in a dataframe or pytable?

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import tables as pytb

with pytb.open_file('debug_counts.h5', mode='r') as h5file:

    table = h5file.get_node('/tbl_main') 

    print("number of rows in table =", table.nrows) 

    i = 0 
    j = 0
    for row in table:
        j += 1
        if row['symbol'] == b"foo":           
            i += 1  

    print("table all records count =", j)  
    print("table foo records count =", i)  

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table.read_where('(symbol == b"foo")')) 

    print("dataframe size =", df.size)    

    i = 0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        i += 1

    print("dataframe records count =", i)    

    i = 0 
    for record in table.where('(symbol == b"foo")'):
        i += 1

    print("table.where records count =", i)

    h5file.close()
```

Output:

```
runfile('G:/$HDF5/debug_counts.py', wdir='G:/$HDF5')
number of rows in table = 2826254
table all records count = 2826254
table foo records count = 37920
dataframe size = 985920
dataframe records count = 37920
table.where records count = 37920
```

The larger numbers are all correct. The 37920 numbers are incorrect, or at least not what I want. How do I get the output I'm looking for (985920, not 37920), and where does the 37920 come from?

Comment: Did I not ask this question clearly? I was thinking this would be a Python 101 thing, like I'm just using the wrong syntax and therefore not counting what I think I'm counting. Someone please post if the question is not clear ...

Comment: dts, do you want the number of matching rows or the number of elements in matching rows? Pandas docs say `dataframe.size()` returns total number of elements (rows x columns). All of your pytables methods return 37920 as the count of the rows with `symbol == b"foo"`. Since the difference is 26x, I suspect you have 26 fields/columns. Instead of iterating to count, consider the other pytables `.where_()` operators. See details below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would code to get row and size counts. I couldn't test your example. Apologies if there's an inadvertent typo.

```
import tables as pytb
with pytb.open_file('debug_counts.h5', mode='r') as h5file:
    table = h5file.get_node('/tbl_main')

    sym_list = table.get_where_list('(symbol == b"foo")')
    print("table.get_where_list retrieved =", len(sym_list), "rows" )

    sym_array = table.read_where('(symbol == b"foo")')
    print("table.read_where array dtype=" , sym_array.dtype)     
    print("table.read_where array shape=" , sym_array.shape)
    print("table.read_where array size =" , sym_array.size)
```

Comment: Oops ... my bad for posting such a dumb question. For reasons forgotten I thought my 26x number was the right one and the smaller ones were out of nowhere, hence my confusion. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: No dumb questions when you're learning (ok, yes there are, but this isn't one of them - you wrote the code to figure it out). From experience, I know all the pytables and numpy methods are a little overwhelming at the start.